# How To Show Data From A Nested Array Using Mongoose Filter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I don't know how to write the title but my problem is I had a nested array data in MongoDB which is structured like this :

```
[
 {
  employee: one,
  data: [
           {
             tahun: 2020
           },
           {
             tahun: 2022
           }
        ],
 somedata: ...,
 ..
 },
 {
  employee: two,
  data: [
           {
             tahun: 2019
           },
           {
             tahun: 2022
           }
        ]
 },
 somedata: ...,
 ..
]
```

I wanted to show all the employees but only with the data tahun = 2022. So it should be like this :

```
[
 {
  employee: one,
  data: [
           {
             tahun: 2022
           }
        ]
 },
 somedata: ...,
 ..
 {
  employee: two,
  data: [
           {
             tahun: 2022
           }
        ]
 },
 somedata: ...,
 ..
]
```

I don't know how to filter it with mongoose function `.find()`. By far I can only return the data array (filtered), but not with the entire `employees` data like this :

```
[
  data: [
           {
             tahun: 2022
           }
        ],
  data: [
           {
             tahun: 2022
           }
        ]
]
```

> kocak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$elemMatch`. From mongo docs:

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field
>   with at least one element that matches all the specified query
>   criteria.

```
{ <field>: { $elemMatch: { <query1>, <query2>, ... } } }
```

> If you specify only a single  condition in the $elemMatch expression,
>   you do not need to use $elemMatch.

In your case, this might go something like this:

```
db.employee.find(
   { data: { $elemMatch: { tahun: "2022" } } }
)
```

Note that **employee** here is your model name.

Comment: can I add multiple condition? like this : `db.employee.find(
   { data: { $elemMatch: { tahun: "2022", semester: 1 } } }
)`

Comment: Yes you can, read more here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch

Comment: It did filtering the data, but it still returns with all the data array so it's not like what I'm expected